# "Carried" vs "carrying"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

> When the tank carried/carrying the toxic gas derailed, the firemen tried to isolate the village from all traffic.

Why is "carried" wrong in this sentence? And why should it be "carrying"?

Comment: It is wrong because of the subject and verb: the tank derailed. /carrying the toxic gas/ is  a reduced clause: When the tank *that was carrying*  the toxic gas derailed, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It cannot be past tense which can be a finite verb, else you are saying it is not carrying toxic gas *before* it derailed, but it is. "Carrying" suggests it *was carrying* toxic gas before derailing, which is a participle.

Comment: You should show that "carried" can be a finite verb, but "carrying" is a participle.

Comment: The tank _which was_ carrying the gas.